# wordpressでアップロードしたメディアファイルのURLを変更する方法

Tags: wordpress

wordpressの画像のアップロードを少し前まで、サーバに直接アップロードしていたのですが、
ストレージを別に用意してそちらに画像をアップロードする様にしました。

すると今まで画像のURLは

http://hogehoge.com/wp-content/upload/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/image.jpg

の様になっていたのですが、それが

http://hogehoge.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/upload/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/image.jpg

という感じにドメイン名が変わりました。

ところが、ストレージに切り替える前のファイルのURLは、古い方のURLで、データベースに保存されています。
メディアファイルのURLを一括して新しい方のドメイン名に変更したいく、試行錯誤したのですがうまくいきませんでした。

wordpressでアップロードした画像のURLだけを変更する方法をご存知の方がいらしたら、
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

WordPressのDB内に記述されているURLを変更したいということでよろしいでしょうか？

`Search Replace DB`というツールを使うとよい、という記事を発見しました。
初めはSQLを使って、一括置換すればよいのかと思ったのですが、WordPressの場合、シリアライズされたデータがあり、これをやってしまうと整合性があわなくなるようです。詳細は参考サイトをご覧ください。

参考サイトは少し前の記事ですが、ツール自体はアクティブにメンテナンスされているようで、最近も更新されています。

ただ、私もこのツールを使ったことはないので、あくまで自己責任でご利用ください。ツールの作者さんも全てのケースを想定するのは努力はしているが難しいので、バックアップをとって自己責任で実行するように警告しています。

参考サイト
http://www.infoscoop.org/blogjp/2014/08/14/use-search-and-replace-for-wordpress-when-moving/
http://webcre-archive.com/2012/10/04/wordpress-db-url-replace/

ツールのサイト
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Answer (score 0):

最近メジャーな方法はWP-CLIを使うことでしょうか。
WP-CLIでWordPressをコマンドラインから操作できるのですが、そのコマンドの１つに「search-replace」というものがあります。
これでURLの一括置換が行えるので、サイト移転の際などに重宝されています。
参考記事：http://gatespace.jp/2014/12/02/wp-cli-wp-search-replace/

WP-CLIは公式ドキュメントも英語ながら豊富ですので、この機会にお試しください。
http://wp-cli.org/